# Name that connector.. and cable please

Tags: cables

I would like help figuring out what type of cable and connector are shown in the images.  I have a robotic cd autoloader and the arm stopped working properly and this cable shows signs of wear.  Any help is appreciated.  I know this is a 10 pin cable but I'm not sure what it's actually called.  Is this a standard cable with connectors?  Mine is about 18" long.  If it's not a standard cable is there a person who can make this for me?

Thanks,

Daniel

[image: Connector Image]

[image: Connector Image 2]

Comment: FPC and FPC connector. The connector may be custom.

Comment: FPC: Flexible Printed Circuit. Also, FFC: Flexible Flat Cable. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flexible_flat_cable

Answer (score 1):

It's FPC, i would look at Nicomatic website for datasheets or part numbers. I had visually similar cables from Nicomatic. Looks much like 2.54mm pitch, although you should measure it.

Comment: Try this :http://www.nicomatic.com/product-microflex_flexible_harness-29-en.htm

Answer (score 0):

That's a flat-flex cable.

Digi-Key does semi-custom (standard part number, but made up when you order it) versions that might work for you.  Otherwise, it's fully custom and you're out of luck.

See Digi-Key part number [10-018.75-173-ND](http://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/10-018.75-173/10-018.75-173-ND/) (but the gender's wrong) or try their [parametric search](http://www.digikey.com/product-search/en/cable-assemblies/flat-flex-cables-ffc-fpc/1573426).  You will want to measure the pitch of the connector.

Comment: How do I measure the pitch of the connector?

Comment: measure between the outermost pins with a ruler, divide by (N-1).

Comment: ... Where N = the number of pins being measured across.